# Strange link error. Can't find symbol although nm verifies it is there

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I've got 2 libraries. QtMultimedia and libqavfcamera.
libavfcamera depends on QtMultimedia

I've added a class and its implementation to QtMultimedia and it compiles and links successfully. I can verify (at least I think) that it contains my implementation using nm:

```
$ nm -a -U -j /Users/mnelson/Projects/Surge/Accretive/qt/qt5/qtbase/lib/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/Current/QtMultimedia | grep -i capab | c++filt

qt_meta_data_QCameraCapability
qt_meta_stringdata_QCameraCapability
QCameraCapability::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
QCameraCapability::qt_metacast(char const*)
QCameraCapability::staticMetaObjectQCameraCapability::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
QCameraCapability::QCameraCapability(QSize, double, double)
QCameraCapability::QCameraCapability(QCameraCapability const&)
QCameraCapability::QCameraCapability(QSize, double, double)
QCameraCapability::QCameraCapability(QCameraCapability const&)
QCameraCapability::~QCameraCapability()
QCameraCapability::~QCameraCapability()
QList<QCameraCapability>::QList(QList<QCameraCapability> const&)
QCameraInfo::capabilities() const
QCameraCapability::metaObject() const
QCameraCapability::resolution() const
QCameraCapability::maxFrameRate() const
QCameraCapability::minFrameRate() const
QMediaServiceProvider::cameraCapabilities(QByteArray const&) const
QPluginServiceProvider::cameraCapabilities(QByteArray const&) const
typeinfo for QCameraCapability
typeinfo name for QCameraCapability
vtable for QCameraCapability
```

But when I try to link against that library I get a "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64":

```
$ "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -v -demangle -dynamic -dylib -arch x86_64 -headerpad_max_install_names -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -single_module -o libqavfcamera_debug.dylib -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk .obj/debug/avfcameraserviceplugin.o .obj/debug/avfcameracontrol.o .obj/debug/avfvideorenderercontrol.o .obj/debug/avfcamerametadatacontrol.o .obj/debug/avfimagecapturecontrol.o .obj/debug/avfmediarecordercontrol.o .obj/debug/avfcameraservice.o .obj/debug/avfcamerasession.o .obj/debug/avfstoragelocation.o .obj/debug/avfvideodevicecontrol.o .obj/debug/avfaudioinputselectorcontrol.o .obj/debug/avfcamerainfocontrol.o .obj/debug/avfcameraviewfindersettingscontrol.o .obj/debug/moc_avfcameraserviceplugin.o .obj/debug/moc_avfcamerainfocontrol.o .obj/debug/moc_avfcameraviewfindersettingscontrol.o -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework AppKit -framework AudioUnit -framework QtMultimedia -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework QtNetwork -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a -F/Users/mnelson/Projects/Surge/Accretive/qt/qt5/qtbase/lib
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-236.4
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Users/mnelson/Projects/Surge/Accretive/qt/qt5/qtbase/lib
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QCameraCapability::QCameraCapability(QSize, double, double)", referenced from:
      AVFCameraSession::updateCameraDevices() in avfcamerasession.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

QCameraCapability::QCameraCapability(QSize, double, double) certainly seems to be there. The paths look right. Not sure why it's in there twice.

I'm new to c++ dev on OS X so I'm probably (hopefully) missing something obvious.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually linking to the QtMultimedia library?

Comment: Also, leaving off the "-j" option to nm might be illuminating wrt exactly what kind of symbols are being exported.  Also, you should add "-arch x86_64" to make sure you're seeing symbols for the correct architecture.

Comment: Not totally sure if these options are order dependent, but I would put the `-F` option before the corresponding `-framework`. It makes more sense to me to have the option that adds a directory to the search path before the option that needs to find something in that directory.

Comment: Is Qt managed as a OSX Framework in XCode? Never looked there in detail. Personally i would check if it runs by adding the Qt Lib Path to the Library Search Path, if the framework paths are not checked for libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for your comments as they led me to the solution.

Running nm without the -j option was indeed illuminating.

```
$ nm -a -arch x86_64 QtMultimedia | grep resolution | c++filt
000000000005eef0 T QCameraViewfinderSettings::resolutionChanged(QSize)
0000000000047290 T QMediaResource::resolution() const
000000000002dff0 unsigned short QCameraCapability::resolution() const
0000000000050d70 T QImageEncoderSettings::resolution() const
0000000000050610 T QVideoEncoderSettings::resolution() const
000000000002ce90 T QCameraViewfinderSettings::resolution() const
```

I'm adding code to the QtMultimedia library and the newly added class was missing the export macro Q_MULTIMEDIA_EXPORT.

After adding the macro and recompiling the nm output looks like:

```
$ nm -a -arch x86_64 -U QtMultimedia | grep resolution | c++filt
000000000005f0f0 T QCameraViewfinderSettings::resolutionChanged(QSize)
0000000000047490 T QMediaResource::resolution() const
000000000002e1f0 T QCameraCapability::resolution() const
0000000000050f70 T QImageEncoderSettings::resolution() const
0000000000050810 T QVideoEncoderSettings::resolution() const
000000000002d090 T QCameraViewfinderSettings::resolution() const
```

After which it linked just fine.